# Python / asyncio: How to test GraphQL subscriptions?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, graphql, python-asyncio

I have created a GraphQL API on AWS AppSync and I need to run tests to verify things work as expected.

I have implemented a command line API client in Python with [`gql`](https://pypi.org/project/gql) to interact with the API:

- I can run queries ✅
- I can run mutations ✅
- I can start a subscription, run a matching mutation in a second Terminal tab and see the expected message from the subscription about the change in the first tab ✅

Alternatively, I can use the AWS AppSync console to perform the same actions.

Further, I have created a suite of tests that use [`pytest`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest) along with various plugins (most prominently [`pytest-asyncio`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio)):

- Tests for queries and mutations were straight-forward to implement; they work fine. ✅

However, I am struggling with implementing the subscription tests: As opposed to queries and mutations, a subscription run by itself obviously doesn't really do anything, it only responds to changes to the API resource it is subscribed to (typically triggered by a mutation); testing a subscription therefore needs to take the following actions:

1. start the subscription under test
2. run a mutation that changes the API resource the subscription is subscribed to
3. assert the subscription reports the expected API resource change
4. stop the subscription under test

There is sample code in the [`gql` docs](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/async_advanced_usage.html) for running multiple GraphQL queries in parallel using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), but unfortunately, that example just keeps running until stopped manually (e.g. using `CTRL-C` or so) - which obviously is not an option for a test suite that should run non-interactively.

#### My problem:

I don't know how to use `asyncio` to implement the steps above.

Subscriptions are run asynchronously, see for example `execute_subscription1` in the `gql` docs linked above. How do I do step 1 / start a subscription (which implies `await`ing it, doesn't it ?) - while staying unblocked in the main thread, so I can do step 2 / run a mutation ? I tried using [`asyncio.to_thread(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread), but from what I understand, using that with `await asyncio.gather(...)` as shown in the linked Python docs (and my sample code below), i.e. running a function in a separate thread doesn't seem to mean I'm decoupled from it, does it ? I'm still blocked waiting for the subscription function to finish (which never happens...)

I *think* I should be able to figure out step 3 by myself - but looking ahead to step 4, it seems I need to create a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) and [`cancel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) that, right ?

One further problem: The entire system doesn't seem exactly super fast: Running any operation takes a couple of seconds at least and a subscription doesn't seem to start listening immediately, but takes a little to start up. Therefore, the mutation might already have happened before the subscription was ready.
I might need some mechanism to ensure step 2 is only kicked off once step 1 has fully started up. I *think* [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) or [`asyncio.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Condition) might help - but considering the amount of question marks over my head right now, it seems advisable to run all this by the SO swarm first.

#### My question:

How do I run an asynchronous function (the subscription), then run the mutation (sync ? async ?) and then cancel the asynchronous one - all in the same process (possibly in different threads) ?

#### What I have so far:

The code I have so far is rather involved, it's not easy to reduce it to a digestable form - let alone present a concise, self-contained working example here (which anyway mandates access to the AppSync API); trying anyway to give some idea:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport import aiohttp, appsync_auth, appsync_websockets

# authenticate with AWS Cognito to get a JWT
access_token = _get_access_token()
# get this from AWS AppSync console
endpoint = '<some random ID>'

host     = f'{endpoint}.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
url_gql  = f'https://{host}/graphql'
url_wss  = f'wss://{endpoint}.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql'

auth = appsync_auth.AppSyncJWTAuthentication(host=host, jwt=access_token)


def run_subscription():
    query = gql('''
    subscription mySubscription {
      ...
    }
    ''')

    transport = appsync_websockets.AppSyncWebsocketsTransport(auth=auth, url=url_wss)
    client = Client(transport=transport)

    print ('run_subscription')

    for result in client.subscribe(query):
        print (f'subscription result: {result}')


# from https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/basic_usage.html:
#    basic example won’t work if you have an asyncio event loop running
# --> I _think_ I need to run asynchronously:
#   https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/async/async_usage.html
async def run_mutation():
    query = gql('''
      mutation myMutation($mut_var: SomeType!) {
        ...
      }
      ''')

    params = {"mut_var": {
        ... (data for SomeType) ...
      }}

    print ('run_mutation')

    transport  = aiohttp.AIOHTTPTransport(auth=auth, url=url_gql)
    async with Client(transport=transport) as session:
        result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=params)
        print (f'mutation result: {result}')


async def main():
    # THIS IS WHAT I AM STRUGGLING WITH:
    # I don't think I can just start both functions together...
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(run_subscription),
                         run_mutation())
    # TODO: how do I stop the mutation here ?


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
run_mutation
run_subscription
mutation result: ... (matches expectation) ...
```

From what I understand, `run_subscription` and `run_mutation` are started simultaneously and the subscription is not ready to listen yet, hence no output from it.

#### More thoughts:

I am somewhat surprised I haven't been able to find a lot of online resources about this (JavaScript example [here](https://speckle.systems/blog/testing-gql-subs)) - doesn't anyone test their subscriptions ?!? Also, am I at least heading in the general right direction ? I thought about pivoting the entire approach and start the subscription as a pytest fixture, but that really seems weird, sort of makes the subject under test a part of the test environment...

I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could turn your `run_subscription()` function into an async function as well, then call it via `asyncio.create_task()` in your main function. This way it will run in the background.

So your main would look something like:

```py
async def main():
    subscription_task = asyncio.create_task(run_subscription())
    await run_mutation()
    subscription_task.cancel() #to stop the task running in the background
```

You still might get runtime problems with the subscription not being ready when you try to modify it.
A hacky way to test it quickly is to simply add a `await asyncio.sleep(1)` after creating the subscription task.

The more elegant way would be to create an top level `future = asyncio.Future()` and once you received a result for your subscription, you set this `future.set_result()`. But take care, you can only set the result once, so only do it one time (e.g. by checking `future.done()`).

You then can simply do an `await future` after your `run_subcription()` to ensure that the subscription was created before doing any mutations.

Also there most possibly are better ways to stop you subscription, but I am not familiar with that gql module.

Edit: Concerning your more general question about testing. I don't really like to depend on external components for my tests. Because the tests might fail without you having anything to do with it. There can be network problems, delayed and slow communication, someone could have messed up the server side and so on. Then your tests fail although your code is fine.

So I prefer to mock the subscription/communication process all within my test environment. Sure, if you change something in that communication chain you will have to update you mock setup. But this way you can be sure that there are no external factors that might let your tests fail.

Of course, mocking a whole communication chain can be quite annoying and time consuming, but I still prefer it. Which does not mean that I do not have 3rd party dependencies within my test setups, reality is often not how you'd like it to be ;)